# Does Auth0 support SOAP based binding in SAML configuration?

Tags: soap, saml, auth0

I was looking through older documentation and it seems it was once supported but I don't see any reference of SOAP based SAML bindings in Auth0 anymore. Is there a way or did they stop supporting it ?

I tried looking into the the latest docs and found nothing.